# Is a student attending an university in Massachusetts and interning for over 183 days in California count as a "Resident" for MA income tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, massachusetts

Does a student attending a university in Massachusetts and interning for over 183 days (in the same fiscal year) in California count as a "Resident" for Massachusetts income tax purposes?

I'm reading what seems to be contradicting information:

https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2935027-son-had-college-internship-out-of-state-questions-about-filing-taxes ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190325200359/https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2935027-son-had-college-internship-out-of-state-questions-about-filing-taxes)):

> A student who is away to attend school is still considered a resident of his home state/city for tax purposes. He will be a non-resident everywhere else.

https://www.mass.gov/technical-information-release/tir-95-7-change-in-the-definition-of-resident-for-massachusetts ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190325200416/https://www.mass.gov/technical-information-release/tir-95-7-change-in-the-definition-of-resident-for-massachusetts)):

> (f) "Resident" or "inhabitant", (1) any natural person domiciled in the commonwealth [[=](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_(U.S._state)) state of Massachusetts], or (2) **any natural person who is not domiciled in the commonwealth but who maintains a permanent place of abode in the commonwealth and spends in the aggregate more than one hundred and eighty-three days of the taxable year in the commonwealth**, including days spent partially in and partially out of the commonwealth.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. (2) requires a permanent abode in the commonwealth *and* presence for 183+ days. This student only attends university (which does not, I believe, by itself establish a permanent abode) *and* spent fewer than 183 days in MA (because of the lengthy internship in CA).

Comment: @chepner From understanding the first quote says that the student would be considered a MA resident whereas the second quote implies that the student would not be considered a MA resident because he spent fewer than 183 days in Massachusetts.

Comment: No, the first quote says he's still a resident of his *home* state, which I assumed here was not MA.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, good catch, let's assume his home is MA (except when he was doing the internship: he was living in CA).

Comment: You should look up whether "permanent place of abode" includes whatever accomodations you stayed in during your time in MA, IIRC college dorms don't count. Also, if you spent 183 days in CA you didn't spend 183 in MA, so why would that apply to you anyway?

Comment: OK, in that case he's most likely a resident of MA, despite spending 183+ days in CA. I think the *intent* is to allow people in situations like this to relocate without officially moving. I don't know where a strict line is drawn; it may come down to intent. For students, it's usually pretty clear. They still live with their parents, but aren't physically present at their parent's abode.

Comment: Put another way, in this case simply spending an extended period of time in CA was not sufficient (due to established residency in MA and intent to return) to make the student a resident of CA rather than MA. (And I'm not sure it's *required*, but the student may be *able* to claim part-year residency in both states if that would be beneficial.)

Comment: From your other comments it looks like you/the student are domiciled in MA and subject to taxes from that clause, the bolded one is irrelevant. Incidentally, you likely owe CA tax on the internship pay.

Comment: Note that is possible that he is considered a _resident_ in both states (and owes taxes in both). Nothing forces different states to have a harmonized appraoch to residency rules.

Comment: @Aganju that may apply to some combinations of states. Not this case (CA/MA) though.

Comment: It seems we're missing an important piece of information: are you actually a resident of Massachusetts, or a resident of some other state attending school there?

Comment: @jamesqf I'm unsure how to define residency. When attending school in MA, the student lives in MA. He doesn't live anywhere else in the US except when doing the internship in CA.

Comment: I think the question here is does the student have a PERMANENT residency that he plans to return to at such time that he does not have an internship or classes?  Is there an address listed on the student's ID/license other than the CA address or the MA dorm address?

Comment: @Steve-o169 he's a graduate student who stays on  campus pretty anytime aside from internships and vacation. MA dorm is used for American IDs.

Comment: So I would say in this case, the student fits more into part 1 of the second quote than part 2. It seems that the student is "domiciled" in MA by this definition of the term: `a place to which, even if he or she were temporarily absent, they intend to return`.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt: In most cases, establishing residency for a college student ought to be pretty simple.  Did s/he go to high school in the state?  If it's a state university, does s/he pay out-of-state tuition?

Comment: @jamesqf the student went in France for high school and undergraduate studies. The student later going joined a US university in MA for PhD studies: the student is supported by some grant that pays for the university tuition fees and gives some stipend to the student (common situation of PhD students in the US).

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt: So it's an international student, not someone who is a US citizen?  I think that might get into other problems that I don't know anything about.  I'd suggest asking the international student office of the university.  They've probably encountered similar situations before.

Comment: @jamesqf correct, F1-student.